# Defaulting the Quantity and Cost on an Opportunity product line item

Tags: pricebook

We have a custom field on our `Opportunity Product` that is called `IIS Cost` and we would like for some `Product` records to be able to have this value defaulted from the `PricebookEntry`. For example I can default the `Sales Price` but not my `IIS Cost`.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you using out-of-box Opportunity product selection user interface 'Add product' button? If so, you can do this via workflows

Comment: Hi There,
Yes we are using the out of box opportunity product items. We created a field called "Standard Cost" in the pricebook page layout. Thats where we want to put the default cost but we want this to pull through all the way through to the opportunity product with the ability to change it as needed. Just like the sales price. Can you help me with this workflow?
Thanks.
R-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth reviewing the schema between these SObjects: Opportunity, Opportunity Product, Pricebook Entry, Product2, Pricebook2

1. Create a New Workflow on Opportunity Product
2. Evaluate the rule only upon Creation
3. Formula evaluates to true expression is simply `true` - that is, the WF runs every time an Opportunity Product is created
4. Workflow Action is a Field Update of field `IIS_Cost__c` defined to be the value of (use Formula Value to set value) `Opportunity.Pricebook2.standard_cost__c`

This sequence works because before the Opportunity Product can be created, SFDC prompts for a Pricebook to assign to the Opportunity.  Hence, when the workflow executes upon creation of the Opportunity Product, the lookup relationship from `Opportunity Product -> Opportunity -> Pricebook2` exists, allowing you to select `Standard_Cost__c`

As IIS Cost is presumably a currency field, it can be edited by the user after the Opportunity Product is created.

Curiously, SFDC does not permit traversal of the relationship: `Opportunity Product -> PricebookEntry -> Pricebook2` in a workflow field update formula.

Note also  that I wold think that Standard Cost really belongs as a custom field on PricebookEntry or arguably, on Product2 as standard cost is associated with a SKU, not a pricebook - but I'm sure you know your application better than I.

Answer (score -1):

we can create the formula field

Comment: How do you see a formula field entering a default value in another field, where the vaue should still be editable ?